# How to change background color on hover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3.3.7 in my project.

I have this button:

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnExecute" value="Submit" />
```

How can I make the button background black and the text white, but on mouse hover I want to make the background white and the text black?

Comment: This is incredibly lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do that easily. Just style it with CSS and use a `:hover` rule.

```css
#btnExecute {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#btnExecute:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnExecute" value="Submit" />
```

It should work just like that, but if Bootstrap tries to override it, just add `!important` to the settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply css and do this

--CSS--

```
btn btn-sm:hover { 
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't set the background or color when not hovering, nor does it set the text color to black when hovering.